# Uncaught TypeError Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the jquery msgbox addon found here:

http://jquerymsgbox.yazdimoldu.tk/

The function call is like so:

```
function forceRing(){
 $.msgBox({
  title:"Selam / Hello",
  content:"Merhaba Dünya! / Hello World!"
 });
};
```

But I receive the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'msgBox'
forceRingindex.php:38
(anonymous function)index.php:275
onclick

Comment: I'd guess that, for whatever reason, the `msgBox` script hasn't been loaded...

Comment: Make sure the load order of scripts is correct, jQuery first then msgBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you didn't properly include the JavaScript file for the MsgBox plugin. Are you sure that you have first included jQuery and then the msgBox plugin?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="....jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="....jquery.msgbox.js"></script>
```

...or how the files are called?

Note, an often silly error is to not properly write the JavaScript tag. Like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".." />
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".."></script>
```

Comment: Loaded in this order:  <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.msgBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/msgBoxLight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Try to open up Firebug or similar tool (depending on your browser). Then in the network section of the tool verify whether the jquery.msgBox.js has been retrieved correctly.

Comment: What an idiot, for not sharing his solution. I have the same problem.  I'm really happy for him though.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with the jquery version.   The msgbox demo page works using jquery-1.11.0.  I got it working using jquery 3.2.1 and jquery-migrate 3.0.0.